# How to make terraform apply stop if there is already a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I am using Terraform to build my cluster. I want to add a setting such that if there already is a cluster on the provided ip in variables.tf, even if there are changes in the other variables, then `terraform apply` should just exit.

Is there a functionality like this?

I know I can use `terraform plan` before `apply` to see the changes and proceed according to that but `terraform plan` is really hard to read, I am open to other solutions as well. I just don't want to break something without knowing.

Comment: No. There is no functionality in TF to check if a resource exist or not.

Comment: Ok thanks. I probably write my own script for it then